# Why are my chilli pepper plants not blossoming?

Tags: peppers

All those plants are not blossoming but healthy

[image: all those plants are not blossoming but healthy]

This one is blossoming

[image: the one is blossoming]

I planted more then 50 chilli pepper plants but just one of them gave blossoms.
Others are growing well but have no blossoms.
What should I do please?

Comment: pictures please

Comment: Too much fertilizer? Too much water? Not enough time from seeding? Without detail it is difficult to make hypotheses.

Comment: I plant them indoor and the one which is blossoming is as V shape 2 branches but others just one branch I have all the seeds from one place, sorry but I don't know how can I send pictures here to show you

Comment: @Raffikarjian if you use the [edit] function, there’s a “picture” icon that opens up a pop-up guiding you through the process.

Comment: You say indoors, but say nothing about the growing conditions. We don't know your climate or even your continent, we don't know how much light they're getting, etc.

Comment: The soil is mixed sand soil, for indoor planting, about 6 hours under the sun, given 2 times nitrogen, PH of soil is 5.8, water 2 or 3 days.